# How to get the average from 3 values on a table on SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, average

I have the following situation on my database:

```
        id:   |   second id:  |  value 
Row 1:  1     |    1          |   123
Row 2:  1     |    2          |   234
Row 3:  1     |    3          |   456
Row 4:  2     |    1          |   987
Row 5:  2     |    2          |   876
Row 6:  2     |    3          |   765
Row 7:  3     |    1          |   345
Row 8:  3     |    2          |   678
Row 9:  3     |    3          |   543
Row 10: 4     |    1          |   345 
...
```

For each id I have 3 second ids, they are always 1,2 and 3.
What I need to do is get the average of this 3 values (contemplating the 3 valus for id) and get the average of them. I need to do this with a long table (I was wondering about creating a specific view to do this).

Any help will be welcome.

(Sorry for my question, but i really begginer on SQL Server)

Comment: I don't know much about MSSQL, but I know that PostgreSQL and Oracle have window functions--ie you can call `avg(value) over (partition by second_id)`, and that will get you what you want.  Does MSSQL have something like that?

Comment: I need a new row, using the average of the 3 values for each id, for the first id i whould have: id: 1 | second id: avg | value: 271

Comment: For the second id i will have this: id: 2 | second id: avg | value: 876

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use AVG and group by each id only.

```
SELECT id, AVG(value)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Wow, that was really simple, i was just complicating it. Thank you all very much for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any kind of window function, a self-join should also work:

```
select id, second_id, value, avg_val_over_id
from(
    select id, second_id, value
    from table
    )a
join(
    select id, avg(value) as avg_val_over_id
    from table
    group by id
    )b
using(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Per your comment, try:

```
SELECT id, AVG(value)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: I need a new row, using the average of the 3 values for each id, for the first id i whould have: id: 1 | second id: avg | value: 271

Comment: I think it's grouping without [second id] column, otherwise it will return the same data as in the sample

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're after, but if you want the average for each of the `second_id`s try:

```
SELECT second_id, AVG(value)
FROM table
GROUP BY second_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want accuracy, use

```
SELECT second_id, AVG(value*1) FROM table GROUP BY second_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to add these average rows in your output, something like this might work (here, I'm creating the sample data inline, and aliasing it as T - it could easily select the basic data from a table instead):

```
select ID,COALESCE(CONVERT(varchar(10),subid),'avg'),AVG(val) from (
select 1 as id,1 as subid,123 as val union all
select 1,2,234 union all
select 1,3,456 union all
select 2,1,987 union all
select 2,2,876 union all
select 2,3,745
) t
group by ID,subid with rollup
having ID is not null
```

Result:

```
1   1   123
1   2   234
1   3   456
1   avg 271
2   1   987
2   2   876
2   3   745
2   avg 869
```